# yii, action calling a different view

Tags: php, yii

I am currently working on a Yii framework project, and I would like to create a button that is an easy pick for the users.  Basically, they push the button, the onclick calls an action, the action sets an array and $_POST the array to the current page (refreshes the page)
The page will use that array to loads accordingly.

Any help would be nice.  If I am doing this and there is a better way, please let me know.

VIEW for the complete view ( http://mysticpaste.com/view/ZWOdXXkESf?2 )

```
<a href="/index.php/ticket/easypicks/<?php echo $ticket['ID'];?>">Easy Pick</a>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['my_picks']))    //if it's $_POSTed
{
$my_picks =$_POST['my_picks'];   //set the variable
}
if(!isset($my_picks)){           //if the variable isn't set
    $my_picks = Picks::model()->find_tickets_by_ID($ticket_ID);
}
print_r($my_picks); ?>           //print out the array
```

Controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    if(isset($_POST['Ticket']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Ticket'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->ID));
    }
    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

public function actionEasypicks($id){
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    $my_picks = Ticket::model()->easy_pick(); // returns an array of 16
    //This is where I think my issue is.  I would like to go to page
    // 'localhost/index.php/ticket/update/3' but what I am redirect to is
    // 'localhost/index.php/ticket/easypicks/3'
    // currently this gives me an "Undefined index"
    $url = 'localhost/index.php/ticket/update/3';
    $this->redirect($_POST[$url],$my_picks = $my_picks);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is better suited to have one action of update and let it handle the special scenario for running easy picks by setting a hidden input.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    if(isset($_POST['easy_picks'] && $_POST['easy_picks']){
        $my_picks = Ticket::model()->easy_pick(); // returns an array of 16
        $model->attributes = $my_picks;
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->ID));
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Ticket']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Ticket'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->ID));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Then for your javascript stuff

```
function easy_picks(){
    var url = '/index.php/ticket/update/'+<?php echo $ticket_ID; ?>;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { easy_picks : 1},
        success: function(){
            //do something here like a refresh or redirect
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where would this go? and how does it post the array created my the easy_picks function?

Comment: how are you creating your form in your view?

Comment: I am not using CActiveForm.  
It's a lot of radio buttons, and I use Javascript to select the data.

Comment: please update your original post to include your view's form or at least a sample of the form tag and the inputs.

Comment: The original view is linked in the question now.  The regional view is an array of buttons.  16 sets of 4 radio buttons, one being in each view.  Please let me know if you need to see that too.

Comment: That ajax call that you pasted up there,  That is for the save button.  The save button works already, I am currently working on an easy pick button.

Comment: @SirRahal55, I think this better represents what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: so I tried what you put in, and I changed up the JS a little.  here it is ( http://mysticpaste.com/view/azIMeQ2a2c?3 ).  The page reloads, but the easy_picks array never gets posted.